# Remove elements from the DOM inside $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have list of elements and on certain event I want to destroy them from the dom.

```
if (appendedElements.length > 0) {
    $.each(appendedElements, function (i) {
        $(i).remove();
   })
}
```

`appendedElements` are of course greater than zero but I'm not deleting elements. What's wrong with this code?

Comment: share the whole code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the first argument of the parameter method is an index of the element, not the element itself. This one is passed as a second parameter. Try:

```
if (appendedElements.length > 0) {
    $.each(appendedElements, function (i, element) {
        $(element).remove();
       //i = 0, 1, 2....
   })
}
```

The whole reference with examples you can find here:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Answer (score 2):

If the `appendedElements` is a jQuery object or is an array of dom element references then there is no need to iterate, you can just call the `remove` method like

```
$(appendedElements).remove();
```

As already suggested the problem is the first param to the `each` callback is the index of the item, not the item itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (appendedElements.length > 0) {
    $.each(appendedElements, function (i) {
        $(this).remove(); // use this
   })
}
```

Comment: well, this should work as well, not exactly what jquery recommends, also problematic if you want to bind the method with other object :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the second argument of the [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) callback function:

```
if (appendedElements.length > 0) {
    $.each(appendedElements, function (index, element) {
        $(element).remove();
   })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it without `.each` for example if you have list... something like that

```
<ul id="columar">
  <li>ok</li>
  <li>ok</li>
  <li>ok</li>
  <li>ok</li>
</ul>
```

if you wanna remove the li list you can wiht this code:

```
if (2 == 2) {
  $('#columar li').remove()
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4hgzrLsa/)